# How do I randomly rearrange a line in a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file `test.txt` with lines of text terminated by `.`

I would like to replace one random word from each line with asterisks and append that word to the end of line.

Example:

```
Lorem ipsum is a great generator.
```

Would change to

```
Lorem **** is a great generator. ipsum
```

This was my attempt to select a random word:

```py
import random
    
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readln()
    words = list(map(str, lines.split()))
    print(random.choice(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

string = "Lorem ipsum is a great generator."

strlist = string.split()

rndmindex = random.randint(0, len(strlist) - 1)

replacedItem = strlist[rndmindex]

newString = string.replace(replacedItem, '****')

res = newString + replacedItem


print(res)
```

This will replace any word randomly with '****'

Please comment if you need explanation.